# Setting Environment variables with Rubber/Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rubber

I need to set some environment variables programmatically before my rubber instances start the webserver. I've set the environment variables in the `config/rubber/common/rubber.profile` file. When I ssh into the instance, the Env variables are set properly and if I run the Rails console the variables are loaded in the environment. However, the webserver appears to be loaded prior to the env variables being set. The apis fail on the web server due to the initializers having blank ENV vars. How do I make sure that Rubber sets the bash profile prior to starting the web server?

Comment: are you using passenger as a webserver?

Comment: Yes I'm using passenger. I'm using this template: https://github.com/rubber/rubber/tree/master/templates/complete_passenger_postgresql